# Importar tabla en línea separada con `;`

Tags: r, packages

Quiero importar una tabla de datos separados por `;` que podría ver [ahí](https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt). Lo reproduzco por parte aquí:

```
Price Indices - EURO Currency
Date    ;Blue-Chip;Blue-Chip;Broad    ; Broad   ;Ex UK    ;Ex Euro Zone;Blue-Chip; Broad
        ;  Europe ;Euro-Zone;Europe   ;Euro-Zone;         ;            ; Nordic  ; Nordic
        ;  SX5P   ;  SX5E   ;SXXP     ;SXXE     ; SXXF    ;    SXXA    ;    DK5F ; DKXF
31.12.1986;775.00 ;  900.82 ;   82.76 ;   98.58 ;   98.06 ;   69.06 ;  645.26  ;  65.56
01.01.1987;775.00 ;  900.82 ;   82.76 ;   98.58 ;   98.06 ;   69.06 ;  645.26  ;  65.56
02.01.1987;770.89 ;  891.78 ;   82.57 ;   97.80 ;   97.43 ;   69.37 ;  647.62  ;  65.81
05.01.1987;771.89 ;  898.33 ;   82.82 ;   98.60 ;   98.19 ;   69.16 ;  649.94  ;  65.82
06.01.1987;775.92 ;  902.32 ;   83.28 ;   99.19 ;   98.83 ;   69.50 ;  652.49  ;  66.06
```

Intento obetenerla con `fread` pero me devuelva una error :

```
mydat <- fread('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt', sep = ";")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  211k    0  211k    00     0     750k      0 --:-- --:--:-- --:--:-:-- --:--:--  750k
Error in fread("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt",  : 
  Expecting 9 cols, but line 3887 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=';' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fread("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt",  :
  Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too few or too many items to be column names or data: Price Indices - EURO Currency
2: In fread("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt",  :
  Unable to find 5 lines with expected number of columns (+   last)
```

El objetivo es construir una cartera mensual reequilibrada de Contribución Igual al Riesgo (Iqual Risk Contribution) con R sobre el universo de inversión STOXX Europe 600 Index.

En efecto me dice que *la línea 3887 contiene texto después de procesar todas las columnas* y que *es muy probable que esto se deba a que uno o más campos tienen incrustado sep = ';' y / o (sin escape) '\ n' caracteres dentro de comillas no escapadas no balanceadas*

#### Actualización con la respuesta de Patricio Moracho

Quería seguir usando fread, dado que es más rápida y hacerlo usando los mismo parámetros anteriores pero me dio las mismas errores aunque añadí `skip = 4`:

```
> mydat <- fread('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt', skip= 4, sep = ";")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0   100  211k    0  211k    0     0       0     0   106k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01-  0:00:01 --:--:--  119k
Error in fread("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt",  : 
  Expecting 9 cols, but line 3887 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=';' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt",  :
  Unable to find 5 lines with expected number of columns (+   last)
```

La otra respuesta de Patricio Moracho funciona.

#### Actualización con la respuesta de Hubert Ronald

Parece que no puedo descargar `pack` (data.tables) porque que no exist.

```
> if (!pack %in% installed.packages()) install.packages(pack)
> library(pack)
Error in library(pack) : there is no package called ‘pack’
```

Sin embargo parece que ya tengo el `pack` porque no lo descargo con la línea del if.

Comment: Hola @ThePassenger, he visto que obtienes `Error in library(pack) : there is no package called ‘pack’` esto sucede porque `pack` es una variable, hay que asignarle un valor previamente `pack <- 'data.table'` en tal sentido, al no tener instalado el paquete `'data.table'` la respuesta que te dio @PatricioMoracho (que es correcta) relacionada a la función `fread` no será reconocida por **R**, prueba hacer la instalación directamente en todo caso: `install.packages('data.table')` y luego incluye el citado paquete: `library('data.table')` para que puedas usar la función `fread` sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con este archivo:

- Una primer fila que "rompe" la estructura
- Otras tres filas que son solo encabezados
- Una columna de fecha que hay que modificar para poder transformarla en una fecha.

Podemos usar una función base como `read.table()` para leer el archivo en primer lugar:

```
url <- 'https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt'
df <- read.table(url, sep = ';', skip = 4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Podemos leer directamente desde la url, el separador es `;` y le decimos que ignore las primeras 4 líneas (`skip = 4`) y no queremos que nos convierta las cadenas en `factors` mediante `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Lo que nos resta es darle nombres a las columnas, ya que es complicado leerlo directamente de este archivo simplemente hacemos:

```
names(df) <- c('Date','SX5P','SX5E','SXXP','SXXE','SXXF','SXXA','DK5F','DKXF')
```

Y por último, convertimos la cadena de fecha en un `Date`:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(sub('(.{2}).(.{2}).(.{4})', "\\3-\\2-\\1", df$Date))
```

Resultado final:

```
 head(df)

        Date   SX5P   SX5E  SXXP  SXXE  SXXF  SXXA   DK5F  DKXF
1 1986-12-31 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
2 1987-01-01 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
3 1987-01-02 770.89 891.78 82.57 97.80 97.43 69.37 647.62 65.81
4 1987-01-05 771.89 898.33 82.82 98.60 98.19 69.16 649.94 65.82
5 1987-01-06 775.92 902.32 83.28 99.19 98.83 69.50 652.49 66.06
6 1987-01-07 781.21 899.15 83.78 98.96 98.62 70.59 651.97 66.20
```

Nota: si quieres seguir usando `fread`, (es más rápida que las funciones base) puedes hacerlo usando los  mismo parámetros anteriores

```
mydat <- fread('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt', skip= 4, sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso el reporte indica que la función `fread` no está disponible. Entonces habría que llamar el paquete `'data.table'` pero al no saber si está instalado en el ordenador... habría que instalarlo también.

Una forma de hacer los anterior es:

```
pack <- 'data.table'
if (!pack %in% installed.packages()) install.packages(pack)
library(pack)
```

Básicamente el condicional `if` verifica si está instalado `'data.table'` y si no, lo instala

Por otro lado `library(pack)` podría ser simplemente `library('data.table')` o `library(data.table)` si se tiene el paquete en el sistema, obviando las dos primeras líneas de código.

Las lineas anteriores se podrían emplear en un bucle `for` si se piensa compartir el código con terceros `pack<-c('paquete1','paquete2','paquete3','paquete4')` ya que al no saber las configuraciones de sus equipos, con esta forma se tiene la posibilidad de que el código se ejecute aún con la ausencia de alguno de los paquetes contenido en el precitado vector.

> Entonces el código quedaría así, si ya está instalado el paquete `'data.table'`

```
library('data.table') # o también: library(data.table)
mydat <- fread('https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt', 
                   skip= 4, sep = ";", 
                   col.names = c("fecha", "SX5P", "SX5E", "SXXP", "SXXE", "SXXF", "SXXA", "DK5F", "DKXF")
                   )
mydat$fecha <-as.Date(mydat$fecha, "%d.%m.%Y") # primero se indica la forma que tiene
mydat$fecha <-as.Date(mydat$fecha, "%Y-%m-%d") # luego se le da la forma que se requiere
```

> Adicionalmente voy a incluir también una forma de bajar los datos y limpiarlos para que se pueda ya trabajar con ellos de forma general.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------    
# Se descarga la información y se indica que no tiene "cabeceras"
# para poder personalizarlas
#--------------------------------------------------------------
mydat <- read.delim("https://www.stoxx.com/document/Indices/Current/HistoricalData/hbrbcpe.txt", header=FALSE, sep=";")

# se verifica la cabecera y la parte final de tabla
head(mydat); tail(mydat)

# Dimensiones de la tabla
# el primer valor[1] es fila el segundo [2] columnas
dim(mydat) 

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Se toma los valores de la cuarta fila pero a partir de la segunda columna
# ya que la primera está vacía, por eso se incluye "fecha" dentro de un
# vector con los otros valores
#--------------------------------------------------------------
colnames(mydat)<-c("fecha", "SX5P", "SX5E", "SXXP", "SXXE", "SXXF", "SXXA", "DK5F", "DKXF")

# se elimina las 4 filas de los datos descargados
mydat<-mydat[-(1:4),]

# se reordena los indice de las filas
row.names(mydat) <- 1:nrow(mydat)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# se analiza la naturaleza de los datos
# y se aprecia que todos son factores caracteres
# cuando en verdad la primera columna es del tipo "Date"
# y el resto es "numeric"
#--------------------------------------------------------------    
str(mydat)

# en el caso de la columna "fecha"
# se necesita hacer primero esto
mydat$fecha <-as.Date(mydat$fecha, "%d.%m.%Y")

# Las reglas del ISO 8601 internacional
# expresan un día como "2001-02-03"
# esto es opcional de acuerdo a vuestras necesidades
mydat$fecha <-as.Date(mydat$fecha, "%Y-%m-%d")


#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Se da formato numérico-decimal (double) de la columna 2 a la columna 9->"dim(mydat)[2]"
# se aplica la función "lapply" porque en realidad cada
# columna es una lista, pero hay que definir una función de ayuda
# dicha función es construida a partir de las siguientes referencias
# https://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/?p=5412
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information
#--------------------------------------------------------------
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
mydat[,2:dim(mydat)[2]] <- lapply(mydat[,2:dim(mydat)[2]], as.numeric.factor)


#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Se examina finalmente la naturaleza (clase) de los datos 
#--------------------------------------------------------------
class(mydat); str(mydat)
[1] "data.frame"
'data.frame':   7673 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ fecha: Date, format: "1986-12-31" "1987-01-01" "1987-01-02" ...
 $ SX5P : num  775 775 771 772 776 ...
 $ SX5E : num  901 901 892 898 902 ...
 $ SXXP : num  82.8 82.8 82.6 82.8 83.3 ...
 $ SXXE : num  98.6 98.6 97.8 98.6 99.2 ...
 $ SXXF : num  98.1 98.1 97.4 98.2 98.8 ...
 $ SXXA : num  69.1 69.1 69.4 69.2 69.5 ...
 $ DK5F : num  645 645 648 650 652 ...
 $ DKXF : num  65.6 65.6 65.8 65.8 66.1 ...

 #--------------------------------------------------------------       
 # Se verifica la cabecera y la parte final de la tabla
 #--------------------------------------------------------------
 head(mydat); cat("\n"); tail(mydat)
       fecha   SX5P   SX5E  SXXP  SXXE  SXXF  SXXA   DK5F  DKXF
1 1986-12-31 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
2 1987-01-01 775.00 900.82 82.76 98.58 98.06 69.06 645.26 65.56
3 1987-01-02 770.89 891.78 82.57 97.80 97.43 69.37 647.62 65.81
4 1987-01-05 771.89 898.33 82.82 98.60 98.19 69.16 649.94 65.82
5 1987-01-06 775.92 902.32 83.28 99.19 98.83 69.50 652.49 66.06
6 1987-01-07 781.21 899.15 83.78 98.96 98.62 70.59 651.97 66.20

          fecha    SX5P    SX5E   SXXP   SXXE   SXXF   SXXA    DK5F   DKXF
7668 2016-09-27 2830.24 2970.84 340.19 321.86 405.15 348.15 9010.63 577.18
7669 2016-09-28 2846.55 2991.11 342.57 324.24 407.97 350.45 9072.09 581.27
7670 2016-09-29 2848.93 2991.58 342.72 324.08 407.65 350.90 9112.09 582.60
7671 2016-09-30 2843.17 3002.24 342.92 325.31 408.27 350.09 9115.81 583.26
7672 2016-10-03 2845.43 2998.50 343.23 325.08 408.44 350.92 9131.24 584.32
7673 2016-10-04 2871.06 3029.50 346.10 327.73 411.41 353.92 9212.05 588.71
```

> Puede parecer largo el procedimiento antes codificado, pero siempre se hace necesario una limpieza de datos crudos antes de empezar a modelarlos o efectuar las operaciones de análisis correspondientes.

También aclaro que no es la única forma de hacerlo, todo dependerá con que función se descarguen los datos, si se hace saltos de filas o si ya la función en cuestión puede definir la clase de datos que será cada columna, aquí lo presente paso a paso para que se aprecie el proceso de limpieza cuando se descarga información de terceras fuentes, aunque sé que no fue parte de la pregunta inicial, considero que es oportuno también acotarlo.